# Find unique values and remove duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, unique

Is there anyway to find the unique values and remove those duplicates in excel.

Example

```
Hello
Hello
Dear
Hi
Aloha
Hi
```

The result

```
Dear
Aloha
```

I tried with the standard Remove Duplicates. But it seems like the result is a below.

```
Hello
Dear
Hi
Aloha
```

I'm trying to find unique values, that is around 3000 records from 600k data.

Kindly advice.

Comment: a basic way would be to put a 'count' of the occurrences of each word in the column next to it, then filter by those that have a count of 1. For example, data in A1:A5, in Column B use `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,A1)`

Comment: With that much data, I would suggest a VBA solution.  Try writing the range to an array, then using a Collection or Dictionary object, where you can easily test for duplicates.  Post back with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested on a sample of the size required, but potentially simple and fast is to apply a formula of the kind suggested by @tospig within Conditional Formatting, format with a fill colour and then filter to select and delete that colour.

So please try: select ColumnA, HOME, Styles, Conditional Formating, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, choose a fill colour, OK, OK.

Now filter ColumnA to select that fill colour and delete all visible. If to delete 597k rows this way Excel might have a problem but the filtering might be achieved in stages of limited range each.